# How to add/append to python object?

Tags: python, xlrd

I have a python object that was created and defined by swagger editor. I have written a program to populate it. However, instead of appending it, it keeps replacing previous entries. Below is my code;

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from abc_model import BES as bes
for sheet in wb.sheet():
    if sheet.name == "ABC"
    number_columns = sheet.ncols
    for i in range(2,number_of_columns):
        xyz = bes(name = sheet.cell(19,i).value))
        model.abc_model = xyz
print(model)
```

This only prints and asssign the content of column 4 (assuming there are total 4 columns). However, it should have contents of columns 3 and 4.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `model.abc_model = xyz` try `model.abc_model += xyz`

You're setting your column to the last value obtained, rather than adding them together with your iteration. This is why you're only getting the second value, and not the first or both.

Comment: This did not work, I am getting an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'BES'

Answer (score 0):

As @Dylan Smite mentioned, use `model.abc_model += xyz`. This line of code basically mean that `model.abc_model = model.abc_model + xyz` . It means you add `xyz` to `model.abc_model` and then assign it back to `model.abc_model`

Comment: This did not work, I am getting an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'BES'

Comment: Then, may I know what your bes, abc_model, model, xyz are respectively?

Comment: model is python object and bes is an attribute of that model. xyz is an instance of bes, which I then add to model.abc_model